# SELECT MAX DATE for each ID

Tags: mysql, join, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have two calls this "tipo_hh" and "tipo_hh_historial".

I need to make a join between the two tables, where "id" is the same in both tables.
But I need that for each "id" in the table "tipo_hh" select the "valor" on the table "tipo_hh_historial" with the condition that is the record with "fecha_cambio" and "hora_cambio" maxima.

"id" is primary key and auto increment in the table "tipo_hh"

Something like this.

This is the table "tipo_hh"

```
id  nombre
1   Reefer
2   Lavados
3   Dry
4   Despacho
```

This is the table "tipo_hh_historial"

```
id  valor   fecha_cambio    hora_cambio
1   1.50    27/06/2013  19:15:05
1   5.50    27/06/2013  19:19:32
1   5.50    27/06/2013  19:20:06
1   2.50    27/06/2013  21:03:30
2   4.66    27/06/2013  19:15:17
2   3.00    27/06/2013  19:20:22
3   5.00    27/06/2013  19:20:32
4   1.50    27/06/2013  19:20:50
```

And I need this:

```
id  nombre     valor
1   Reefer     2.50
2   Lavados    3.00
3   Dry        5.00
4   Despacho   1.50
```

Comment: Please view the answers and accept...

Answer (score 4):

Using a sub query to get the max date / time for the historical record for each id, and using that to get the rest of the latest historical record:-

```
SELECT tipo_hh.id, tipo_hh.nombre, tipo_hh_historial.valor
FROM tipo_hh
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fecha_cambio, hora_cambio), '%d/%m/%Y%k:%i:%s')) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM tipo_hh_historial
    GROUP BY id
) Sub1
ON tipo_hh.id = Sub1.id
INNER JOIN tipo_hh_historial
ON tipo_hh_historial.id = Sub1.id
AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fecha_cambio, hora_cambio), '%d/%m/%Y%k:%i:%s') = Sub1.MaxDateTime
```

SQL Fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68baa/2

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should use proper data types for your columns like for date there should a column of type data same as for the time column in you sample data set you have date formatted as `'%d/%m/%Y'` id this could be change to standard format `'%Y-%m-%d'` this will be good to so the below query is for proper types for the columns

```
SELECT t.* ,new_tipo_hh_historial.`valor`
FROM tipo_hh_new t
JOIN (
SELECT  th.*
FROM tipo_hh_historial_new th
JOIN (
SELECT id,valor,
 MAX(fecha_cambio ) fecha_cambio
,MAX(hora_cambio) hora_cambio
FROM `tipo_hh_historial_new` 
GROUP BY id
) thh 
ON (
th.`id` =thh.`id` 
AND th.fecha_cambio=thh.`fecha_cambio` 
AND th.hora_cambio = thh.`hora_cambio`
)
) new_tipo_hh_historial 
USING (id)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d222/1)

And for in case you have date and time stored as string then you need to format them as real types you can use below query but not recommended

```
SELECT t.* ,new_tipo_hh_historial.`valor`
FROM tipo_hh t
JOIN (
SELECT  th.*
FROM tipo_hh_historial th
JOIN (
SELECT id,valor,
 MAX(STR_TO_DATE(fecha_cambio , '%d/%m/%Y')) fecha_cambio
,MAX(TIME_FORMAT(hora_cambio,'%H:%i:%s')) hora_cambio
FROM `tipo_hh_historial` 
GROUP BY id
) thh 
ON (
th.`id` =thh.`id` 
AND STR_TO_DATE(th.fecha_cambio , '%d/%m/%Y')=thh.`fecha_cambio` 
AND TIME_FORMAT(th.hora_cambio,'%H:%i:%s') = thh.`hora_cambio`
)
) new_tipo_hh_historial 
USING (id)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3fec/4)

Your problem seems like the <kbd>[greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)</kbd> problem so you can first get the maxima from your table `tipo_hh_historial` maxima of `fecha_cambio` and `hora_cambio` and need to self join with multiple conditions to get the maximums like i.e

```
ON (
th.`id` =thh.`id` 
AND th.fecha_cambio=thh.`fecha_cambio` 
AND th.hora_cambio = thh.`hora_cambio`
)
```

and then join with your first table to get the expected results

**Edit:** the problem spotted by @Kickstart he already answered so i will provide the another way to overcome.There should be single field to store the date and time for the record like for `fecha_cambio DATETIME` so there will no chance to miss the id and get the correct maxima for date and time.See below updated query

```
SELECT t.* ,new_tipo_hh_historial.`valor`
FROM tipo_hh_new t
JOIN (
SELECT  th.*
FROM tipo_hh_historial_alter th
JOIN (
SELECT id,valor,
 MAX(fecha_cambio ) fecha_cambio
FROM `tipo_hh_historial_alter` 
GROUP BY id
) thh 
ON (
th.`id` =thh.`id` 
AND th.fecha_cambio=thh.`fecha_cambio` 
)
) new_tipo_hh_historial 
USING (id)
```

### [**Updated fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca50c/1)

Comment: Thanks for the response... I already solved my problem... I used this article to solve my issue...http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/. I forgot to note the date field in this question... But i used date data type in my table... you put the solution for both situation. Thanks a lot for the effort... I'm going to give my 50 rep for your response and effort.. Once again thanks...

Comment: Afraid there is a bug in this sql. If for an id the max hora_cambio is not on the max fecha_cambio then it misses the value for that id

Comment: @Kickstart you posted the answer while i was working on the same logic   to overcome your point

Comment: No problem. Fully agree with you that a single datetime field would be better.

Comment: @downvoters care to explain whats wrong you find in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tipo_hh.id, tipo_hh.nombre, tipo_hh_historial.valor
   FROM tipo_hh INNER JOIN tipo_hh_historial 
   ON tipo.id = tipo_hh_historial.id AS 
   group by tipo_hh_historial.id 
   Having max(tipo_hh_historial.hora_cambio);
```

Comment: thanks!... but this is not what i need.. Because I need select the value of "valor" in the same row of the max "hora_cambio" and "fecha_cambio" for each "id"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT A.id, B.nombre, A.valor, MAX(A.hora_cambio) AS hora_cambio_time
FROM tipo_hh_historial AS A
INNER JOIN tipo_hh AS B
ON(A.id = B.id)
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: thanks!... but this is not what i need.. Because I need select the value of "valor" in the same row of the max "hora_cambio" and "fecha_cambio" for each "id"